# ReactJS React-Router Passing Props To Child

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have this Private Router, but am struggling to pass in a prop from the state of my app component. Could someone please explain how to pass in the user object?

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={(props) => authed === true
    ? <Component {...props} />
    : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
/>


export default class App extends Component {
state = {
authed: false,
loading: true,
user: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this Route is inside the App render method, then you can make it like that:

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={(props) => this.state.authed === true
    ? <Component {...props} user={this.state.user} />
    : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
/>
```

Your Component will get the react-router props (history, match, location) and the user that you maintain in your App component state.

Comment: Thanks and if it is outside the App render method, how would I go about doing it then? Thanks.

Comment: If outside means that it is in a component that is somewhere "under" in the component tree, then you would have to pass this user down as props until it reaches the place you need it.